# Transfer files within S3 buckets using AWS Glue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Is there a way to transfer files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using AWS Glue through a Python Script?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a Crawler for your bucket - it will discover the schema of your data and add it as table to Glue Catalog
2. Use Job *wizard* and select your table as source, and *new table* as target
3. Glue will generate the code for you where you have to select the destination of your data, specify format etc.

Comment: This doesn't work for any of the data types not recognized by Glue.

Comment: Why not use s3 service to do it?

Comment: ? what do you mean...doesn't sound like you answered my comment

Comment: I thought you wanted to move data within S3, but glue does not know your data types. You can just move/copy bytes using S3. And by the way - what is your data format? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50348880/transfer-files-within-s3-buckets-using-aws-glue/50351216?noredirect=1#comment117347147_50351216